# Yii2: registerJs() implicitly includes JqueryAsset, how to avoid

Tags: php, jquery, view, yii2, assetbundle

In Yii2 there is a `$this->registerJs()` method available in views for registering inline JS. I use it as described in [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html):

```
$js = "...prepare js code...";
$this->registerJs($js, View::POS_READY);
```

The problem is that with `View::POS_READY` (which is the default for second argument) `registerJs()` implicitly requires `yii\web\JqueryAsset` ([source code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.9/framework/web/View.php#L439)).

But I already included Jquery in my own asset bundle - it is `all-min.js`, there are Jquery + plugins minified and concatenated in a single file. Yii2 includes `JqueryAsset`, therefore duplicating Jquery on a resulting page.

How do I tell Yii2 that Jquery is already included or avoid this duplication in some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily customize jquery asset bundle by configuring `assetManager` in the application components configuration (usually `config/web.php`).

You can disable one or multiple asset bundles by associating `false` with the names of the asset bundles that you want to disable :

```
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles